# Looping through values stripping 1 character at a time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to loop through values and strip 1 character at a time from the values and display the result.

So if I have a table with values:

```
ID
___
34679
13390
89906
```

I want the result to look like this

```
Id
----
4679
679
79
9
3390
390
90
0
9906
906
06
6
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please don't use loops for things like this (I'd also reserve recursive CTEs for scenarios where you have much less control over things, like hierarchies). Loops are bad in SQL; SQL is optimized to work in sets.

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE(ID INT);

INSERT @foo VALUES(34679),(13390),(89906);

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (2048) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number)
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values ORDER BY Number
)
SELECT RIGHT(f.ID, x.n) FROM x
INNER JOIN @foo AS f
ON x.n < LEN(f.ID);
```

Results:

```
9
79
679
4679
0
90
390
3390
6
06
906
9906
```

- http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1
- http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-2
- http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-3

Comment: Thanks allot for your help. this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @MyString varchar(500)

set MyString = '1,2.3#45.#,.6'

select dbo.RemoveChars(MyString, '#,.')

create function [dbo].[RemoveChars] (
    @InputString varchar(MAX)
    ,@CharsToRemove varchar(500)
    )
returns varchar(MAX)
as
begin
    declare @len int
        ,@Counter int
        ,@OneChar char(1)

    set @Counter = 1
    set @len = LEN(@CharsToRemove);

    while (1 = 1)
    begin
        set @OneChar = SUBSTRING(@CharsToRemove, @Counter, 1)
        set @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, @OneChar, '')
        set @Counter = @Counter + 1

        if (
                @Counter > @len
                or @Counter > 20
                )
            break;
    end

    return @InputString
end
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation on how your code works ? That will help future visitors.

Answer (score -3):

```
CREATE PROC udploop (@num varchar(10))
AS
       BEGIN 
             DECLARE @len int; 
             SET @len = LEN(@num); 
             WHILE (@len > 1)
                   BEGIN    
                         SELECT
                            @num = RIGHT(@num, @len - 1); 
                         PRINT @num;
                         SET @len = LEN(@num);
                   END 
       END
```

EXEC:

```
EXEC udploop 34679 
EXEC udploop 13390 
EXEC udploop 89906
```

RESULT:

```
4679 
679 
79 
9 
3390 
390 
90 
0 
9906 
906 
06 
6
```

Comment: So how do you propose you do this, when there are many rows in the table? Call the procedure - in a loop - for every row? Now you need a query to pull all of those values, and then creates the code to call the stored procedure for each one. So you have a loop for every row in the table that calls a procedure that itself runs a loop for every character in every value. This is definitely not an efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: thanks. But, I agree with Aaron. This is not what i wanted. my table have more than 300k values. so this will not work.